# Flow error in package (package deploy)

Tags: visual-workflow

I catch this error during package deployment -

1. (Test-11) JourneysDataTable (Screen Component) - Screen component 'UserDataTable' contains type mapping 'PT' that is not an 'SOBJECT'.
   Test-11: JourneysDataTable (Screen Component) - Screen component 'UserDataTable' contains type mapping 'PT' that is not an 'SOBJECT'.
2. (us_US) The translation for the 'Test-11' flow references the Start screen, which isn't available in the flow.
   us_US: The translation for the 'Test-11' flow references the Start screen, which isn't available in the flow.
3. (de_DE) The translation for the 'Test-11' flow references the Start screen, which isn't available in the flow.
   de_DE: The translation for the 'Test-11' flow references the Start screen, which isn't available in the flow.

How solve it inflow? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

are you deploying via change set? if so, just add the dependencies. Translation should show up there.

If you're deploying via metadata, make sure to check if the tags are correct. Is it really PT? or PT__c?